# Are epimorphic endomorphisms of noetherian commutative rings always injective?

Tags: ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, counterexamples, noetherian

This question was [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3394702/660), but not answered, on Mathematics Stackexchange.

[In this post "ring" means "commutative ring with one".]

Let $A$ be a noetherian ring, and let $f:A\to A$ be an endomorphism which is also an epimorphism.

> Is $f$ necessarily injective?

Eric Wofsey gave an [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3376063/660) of an epimorphic endomorphism of a noetherian ring which is not surjective. (It is well known, and easy to prove, that *surjective* endomorphisms of noetherian rings are automatically bijective.)

[By definition, a morphism of rings $f:A\to B$ is an **epimorphism** if for all pairs of morphisms $(g,h):B\rightrightarrows C$ the equality $g\circ f=h\circ f$ implies $g=h$. Surjective morphisms are epimorphic, but the converse does not always hold: for instance the inclusion $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Q$ *is* an epimorphism.]

---

For more details about epimorphisms see

$\bullet$ MathOverflow thread [What do epimorphisms of (commutative) rings look like?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/109/461).

$\bullet$ Stacks Project Section [Epimorphisms of rings](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04VM).

$\bullet$ [Samuel Seminar](http://www.numdam.org/issues/SAC_1967-1968__2_/) .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is false. I will use freely that $f \colon A \to B$ is an epimorphism if and only if $B \otimes_A B \to B$ is an isomorphism; in particular this is also equivalent to $\operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ being a monomorphism.

> **Example.** Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$, and let
>   $$R = k\left[x,\tfrac{1}{x-1},\tfrac{1}{x-2},\ldots\right].$$
>   Then $R$ has a self-map $x \mapsto x-1$, whose image on spectra is the complement $U$ of the origin. Note that $U \amalg \{0\} \to \operatorname{Spec} R$ is a monomorphism, so the map
>   \begin{align*}
> g \colon R &\to R \times k\\
> x &\mapsto (x-1,0)
> \end{align*}
>   is an epimorphism. Now let $A = R \times k$, and let $f$ be the composition $A \stackrel\pi\twoheadrightarrow R \stackrel g\to A$, where $\pi$ is the natural projection. It is an epimorphism since both $\pi$ and $g$ are, and it is clearly not injective. $\square$
>
> **Picture.** Here is a picture of the situation:[image: A non-dominant self-monomorphism]

**Remark.** However, the result is true if $A$ has a unique associated prime $\mathfrak p$ (i.e. $A$ is irreducible without embedded primes). Indeed, we get an ascending chain
$$\mathfrak p \subseteq f^{-1}(\mathfrak p) \subseteq f^{-1}(f^{-1}(\mathfrak p)) \subseteq \ldots,$$
which stabilises by the Noetherian hypothesis. But if $\operatorname{Spec} A \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ is a monomorphism, in particular it is injective, so this forces $\mathfrak p = f^{-1}(\mathfrak p)$. Then the base change $A_{\mathfrak p} \to (f_*A)_{\mathfrak p}$ of $f \colon A \to f_*A$ along $A \to A_{\mathfrak p}$ is an epimorphism as well, hence so is the composition $A_{\mathfrak p} \to (f_*A)_{\mathfrak p} \to A_{\mathfrak p}$ since it is a further localisation. But this is an epimorphism of *Artinian* rings, hence surjective by [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/101546/82179). Since both rings are Artinian of the same length, we conclude that it's an isomorphism. Since $\mathfrak p$ is the unique associated prime, the map $A \to A_{\mathfrak p}$ is injective, which gives the result.

I'm not sure what happens if $A$ is allowed to have embedded primes. It seems hard to imagine what a counterexample could look like, but I also have no argument to rule it out.

**Remark.** Note also that there are trivial counterexamples without the Noetherian hypothesis, even if $A$ is a domain. For example, $A = k[x_0,x_1,\ldots]$ has a surjective endomorphism that is not injective.

Comment: Thanks! I'm confused. You write: "$f:A\to B$ is an epimorphism if and only if $B\otimes_AB\to B$ is an isomorphism; in particular this is also equivalent to $\operatorname{Spec}B\to\operatorname{Spec} A$ being a monomorphism". I don't understand the second phrase: if $A$ and $B$ are fields and $f$ is not surjective, then $f$ is not an epimorphism but $\operatorname{Spec}B\to\operatorname{Spec} A$ is a monomorphism, right?

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard: sorry, I mean in the category of schemes, not topological spaces.

Comment: That is, the diagonal $\operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} B \times_{\operatorname{Spec} A} \operatorname{Spec} B$ is an isomorphism if and only if the underlying ring map $B \otimes_A B \to B$ is.

Comment: I'm the one who's sorry! I'm most grateful for your awesome answer and your comments! I convinced myself that $R\to R\times k$ is an epi by checking the identity $(p(x),\lambda)\otimes(1,1)=(1,1)\otimes(p(x),\lambda)$ in $(R\times k)\otimes_R(R\times k)$. I hope this argument is correct. Even if it is, I'm sure your approach is more elegant, but I'm not familiar with schemes (to say the least!). I would guess that scheme theory helped you find your example more that it was needed for your proof, but I may be completely wrong...

Comment: I realize that I shouldn't have used the notation $p(x)$ for an element of $R$, since it suggests that it's a polynomial in $x$, instead of a polynomial in $x,1/(x-1),1/(x-2),...$

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard: indeed everything can be checked on the ring level. But I think the schemes picture is much more enlightening, and I have always been unable to think about epimorphisms of rings.